# Critical points of polar curve of given ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

How to find maximum minimum radii and inflection point of a curve with the polar symmetry given by the following ode ? Primed on arc,the angle $\psi$ is made between curve and radial lines. $\theta \text{=const.}$

$$ 2a \psi'=\left(1-\dfrac{T^2}{r^2}\right);\;r'= \cos \psi \; \tag1 $$

[image: WormHole]

Patterns above are drawn for constants $ a=1,T= (4,2) ,\theta_i=\pi/4, r_i=1,s_{max=}=320 a, $ after numerical integration.

The outer maximum radii  are  $ (\approx \sqrt2,2)$ which *could not be found analytically.*

In polar coordinates ... is the following true for local straightness ?

$$\psi^{'}_{inflection}= {0}. \tag 2 $$

Pictorially it does not agree for the first pattern (no inflection), but seems a better tally for the second case where:

$$ r_{inflection} =T \;$$

To find radial extrema

$$\cos \psi=0,\; \psi= \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}..\; \tag 3$$

Differentiating (1)

$$ 2a \psi{''}=\dfrac{2T^2\cos \psi}{r^3} \tag4$$

from (3)

$$ \psi^{''}=0 \tag5 $$

Is it then a correct criterion for finding max/min radii in general ? And further on how can we find $ (r, \theta ) ? $

*Towards a solution for $\psi$*

Let $ u=\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} \to u'= ( r \cos \psi\psi^{'} -\sin \psi \cos \psi)/r^2 \tag6$

Eliminating $ \psi^{'}$ between (1) and (6) and simplifying we obtain

$$\dfrac{u'}{\sqrt{1-u^2r^2}}+ \dfrac{u}{r}= \dfrac{1-T^2/r^2}{2ar} \tag 7 $$

whose integral analytical solution $ u=f(r) $ is required.

Thanking you for the attention.